# update existing entry practices

Tags: php, database

I have an application that allows users to enter reports, there are multiple tables that keep track of the data.

I am working on making an edit form to allow the user to edit an existing entry.

I need help with handeling the update query. Not the actual query, but understanding the best way to handle this.

For example:

A user adds an entry, they could select multiple departments.

Next, they edit that same entry, and select more departments and unselect a couple departments (from when they originally added that entry).

There is a table that keeps track of the entry and what departments it relates to: entry_id, department_id

When doing an update query, how do I update that table appropriately? Do I delete all entries where entry_id = 4 (just using any old number), and then just do an insert w/ all the departments that were selected? I am looking for best practices.

I am not asking for code that does, but just theory.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a good strategy to me. The alternative is to get the set of existing IDs, remove the IDs of this set that are not in the new set, and add the IDs that are in the new set but not in the old one.

But unless you need to keep some additional metadata on the association (time of creation, for example), the delete all and recreate approach is much simpler.